# Return all associated objects in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord

A Company has_many :users.

A User has_many :notes.

How can I return all notes of all users in a company?

```
company.users.notes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up a has_many through association between a company and note

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :notes, through: :users
end
```

Then you can just use `company.notes` to get all notes under a single company

Answer (score 3):

```
company.users.collect(&:notes).flatten
```